# Repeated reference of classes causing text margins to shift

Tags: html, css, margin

When drafting a website, I attempted to use the same `class` 4 different times, consecutively, but noticed that it changed how the text was displayed.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Cgynus - Documentation</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    <div class="topheader">Documentation</div>
  </h1>
  <p>
    <div class="regulartext">Welcome to the official Cygnus programming language documentation.</div>
    <div class="regulartext">This documentation reference manual describes the standard library that is distributed with Cygnus. It also describes some of the optional components that are commonly included in Cygnus distributions.
    <div class="regulartext">Cygnus hosts a standard library that is very extensive and offers a wide range of facilities as indicated by the long table of contents listed below. The library contains built-in modules that provide access to system functionality that would otherwise be inaccessible to Cygnus programmers, as well as modules written in Cygnus that provide standardized solutions for many problems that occur in everyday programming.
    <div class="regulartext">In addition to the standard library, there is a growing collection of several thousand components (from individual programs and modules to packages and entire application development frameworks), available from the Cygnus homepage.</div>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.topheader {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.regulartext {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Why is this happening? How can I get the text to align regularly?

Comment: Did you apply any styling to the body tag or any other parent tags? If so, could you provide the code used, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close two of the div tags, which resulted in the margin issue.

Heres the fixed code:

```css
.topheader {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.regulartext {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
 
    <div class="topheader"> <h1>Documentation</h1></div>
  
  <p>
    <div class="regulartext">Welcome to the official Cygnus programming language documentation.</div>
    <div class="regulartext">This documentation reference manual describes the standard library that is distributed with Cygnus. It also describes some of the optional components that are commonly included in Cygnus distributions.</div>
    <div class="regulartext">Cygnus hosts a standard library that is very extensive and offers a wide range of facilities as indicated by the long table of contents listed below. The library contains built-in modules that provide access to system functionality that would otherwise be inaccessible to Cygnus programmers, as well as modules written in Cygnus that provide standardized solutions for many problems that occur in everyday programming.</div>
    <div class="regulartext">In addition to the standard library, there is a growing collection of several thousand components (from individual programs and modules to packages and entire application development frameworks), available from the Cygnus homepage.</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @Ameer! Silly mistake on my end.